# Improving performance converting bytes into UInt32

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-4.0, c#-7.3

I'm working on source code which processes 2GB of data which represents 60 seconds of network traffic. The total processing time is around 40 seconds. I'm trying to optimize my code for performance as best as possible to try to bring total processing time under the 30 second mark.

[image: Thread Time]

My current analysis in dotTrace shows that 7.62% of the time of the 3.3 million calls my code makes is being spent within the constructor of my Timestamp struct.

[image: Constructor]

Specifically, there are two statements which I'm trying to improve:

```
TimestampHigh = BitConverter.ToUInt32(timestampBytes, 0);
TimestampLow = BitConverter.ToUInt32(timestampBytes, 4);
```

Here is the full struct:

```
public readonly struct Timestamp
{
    public uint TimestampHigh { get; }
    public uint TimestampLow { get; }
    public uint Seconds { get; }
    public uint Microseconds { get; }
    public DateTime LocalTime => new DateTime(EpochTicks + _ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime();

    private const ulong MicrosecondsPerSecond = 1000000UL;
    private const ulong HighFactor = 4294967296UL;
    private readonly ulong _timestamp;

    private const long EpochTicks = 621355968000000000L;
    private const long TicksPerMicrosecond = 10L;
    private readonly long _ticks;

    public Timestamp(byte[] timestampBytes, bool reverseByteOrder)
    {
        if (timestampBytes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(timestampBytes)} cannot be null.");
        if (timestampBytes.Length != 8)
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(timestampBytes)} must have a length of 8.");

        TimestampHigh = BitConverter.ToUInt32(timestampBytes, 0).ReverseByteOrder(reverseByteOrder);
        TimestampLow = BitConverter.ToUInt32(timestampBytes, 4).ReverseByteOrder(reverseByteOrder);
        _timestamp = ((ulong)TimestampHigh * HighFactor) + (ulong)TimestampLow;
        _ticks = (long)_timestamp * TicksPerMicrosecond;
        Seconds = (uint)(_timestamp / MicrosecondsPerSecond);
        Microseconds = (uint)(_timestamp % MicrosecondsPerSecond);
    }

    public Timestamp(uint seconds, uint microseconds)
    {
        Seconds = seconds;
        Microseconds = microseconds;
        _timestamp = seconds * MicrosecondsPerSecond + microseconds;
        _ticks = (long)_timestamp * TicksPerMicrosecond;
        TimestampHigh = (uint)(_timestamp / HighFactor);
        TimestampLow = (uint)(_timestamp % HighFactor);
    }

    public byte[] ConvertToBytes(bool reverseByteOrder)
    {
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
        bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(TimestampHigh.ReverseByteOrder(reverseByteOrder)));
        bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(TimestampLow.ReverseByteOrder(reverseByteOrder)));

        return bytes.ToArray();
    }

    public bool Equals(Timestamp other)
    {
        return TimestampLow == other.TimestampLow && TimestampHigh == other.TimestampHigh;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Timestamp left, Timestamp right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Timestamp left, Timestamp right)
    {
        return !left.Equals(right);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Timestamp other && Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _timestamp.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The method ReverseByteOrder does not seem to incur much of a performance penalty as it represents less than 0.5% of the time according to dotTrace, however here it is for reference:

```
public static UInt32 ReverseByteOrder(this UInt32 value, bool reverseByteOrder)
{
    if (!reverseByteOrder)
    {
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
        Array.Reverse(bytes);
        return BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not create a `ReverseByteToUInt32` extension method instead? It seems wasteful to convert bytes to UInt32 only to convert them back to bytes, reverse them, and convert them to UInt32 again.

Comment: I agree, however, that's a rare case, the reverseByteOrder flag is almost always set to false.

Comment: In dotnet core I'd use one of the binary primitives read / write methods to avoid creating arrays and converting byte order. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a lot of work to fight endianness. That is where [`BitConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=net-5.0) falls on it's face, honestly. The good news is that in modern runtimes we have [`BinaryPrimitives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=net-5.0), which has *endian aware* operations that are then JIT-optimized. Meaning: it is *written* with a check on CPU-endianness, but that check gets removed during JIT, with just the CPU-relevant code being retained. So: avoid [`BitConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=net-5.0). This *does* require a little rework in your code, as the `reverseByteOrder` is no longer an *input*, but consider:

(note: you can pass a `byte[]` in as a `Span<byte>`/`ReadOnlySpan<byte>` - it is implicit)

```cs
public Timestamp(ReadOnlySpan<byte> timestampBytes)
{
    static void ThrowInvalidLength() // can help inlining in some useful cases
            => throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(timestampBytes)} must have a length of 8.");
    if (timestampBytes.Length != 8) ThrowInvalidLength();

     TimestampHigh = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32BigEndian(timestampBytes);
     TimestampLow = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32BigEndian(timestampBytes.Slice(4));
    // ...
}
```

and

```cs
public void ConvertToBytes(Span<byte> destination)
{
    BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt32BigEndian(destination, TimestampHigh);
    BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt32BigEndian(destination.Slice(4), TimestampLow);
}
```

Comment: The project is currently written under a 4.7.2 base, but I see no choice other than move on to 5.0 in order to take advantage of all the new types and methods. Thanks!

Comment: @jscarle they're all available in NuGet packages - System.Memory, System.Buffers, etc; however, .NET Framework doesn't get all the optimization in spans that .NET Core does - the JIT doesn't recognize it as special, etc

Comment: The _can help inlining in some useful cases_ ... is there some blog/some docs on this?